# All Time In Pacific Time

Tags: prepositions, ellipsis, modifiers

While looking at World Cup match schedules, I saw this phrase:

> All times are Pacific Time

I googled a bit and found similar but different phrase:

> All times are ***in*** Pacific Time

So, is one of them wrong?  Is the "in" needed?

Comment: Both are normal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Both are okay and understandable.**

*[The answer ends here.]*

---

But still, if we think a bit further, we find a very little difference.

When it comes to *conversion*, I think more common is using the preposition i.e. *in*. Having said this, *All times are Pacific Times* refers to the times **directly** and on the other hand, adding a preposition ***in*** builds the *context of conversion* from other time zones to the Pacific.

Google results shows the structure with *in* used **more frequently** as compared to the sentence without preposition.

We often come across the charts and tables where the figure from the perspective of *converting different units* is described **with preposition.** For instance, distance *in* kilometer, weight *in* pounds, figure *in* dollars and so **time in Pacific.**

Comment: Just because two phrases are similar but different doesn't always mean that one of them is wrong.

Comment: @SydneyAustraliaESLTeacher *Nobody* said either of them is wrong. I said it's just *preferred*.

Comment: @MaulikV I believe that I can't verify the claim "Google results show the structure with in used more frequently". The best I could do was searching for "times are in Pacific Time", which returned 111 results, compared to "times are Pacific Time", which returned 157 results.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I said similar *structure* not the same *string.* To know the good amount of results, I had to change the search term. As *UTC* time is quite popular, I searched -- *Time is UTC time* and *Time is in UTC time.*

Comment: @MaulikV: meatie (OP) *asked* 'is one of them wrong?'

Comment: @MaulikV "Time is UTC time" returns 93 results."Time is in UTC time" returns only 38 results.

Comment: But "Pacific" isn't a unit: it's an offset.